# Call APOC procedure in apoc.periodic.iterate

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to add new relationships based on a property of existing relationships with the `apoc.create.relationship` function:

```
:auto CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "MATCH (source:Entity)-[r:TEMP_RELATION]->(target:Entity) RETURN source, r, target",
    "CALL apoc.create.relationship(source, r.`Interaction-type`, r, target) YIELD rel RETURN rel",
    {batchSize:5}
    );
```

When I run this query I get Java heap errors (max heap is 8g). It looks like `iterate` is not actually iterating but loading too much into memory. I use Neo4j 4.4.8 on a Mac (M1).

Any ideas why there is a memory leak here?

Comment: You may need to increase your batchsize and set parallel to true

Comment: The point of apoc.periodic.iterate is to run something in batches but it seems to leak memory.

Comment: Imagine this. How many rows is statement1? then put 5 statement2 in one batch for all rows. Then run it one at a time (parallel:False). It might be a lot and your neo4j server is not unlimited resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since neo4j 4 the behavior changed, when you pass a node or relationship to a separate transaction/statement it carries along it's own transaction where it originated from.

So all updates are accumulated on that original transaction.
To avoid that you have to "rebind" the nodes and rels best by returning `id(n) as id` or `id(r) as relId`

Then you can re-match the node and rels in the update statement: `WHERE id(n) = id` and use it from there.
In your example:

```
:auto CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (source:Entity)-[r:TEMP_RELATION]->(target:Entity) RETURN id(source) as sId, properties(r) as props, r.`Interaction-type` as type, id(target) as tId",
"MATCH (source), (target) where id(source) = sId AND id(target) = tId 
 CALL apoc.create.relationship(source, type, props, target) YIELD rel RETURN count(*)",
{batchSize:10000}
);
```